# Increasing and Decreasing Function

Tags: calculus

I have this question. Could somebody do it for me and explain how it is done. Thank you!

A  manufacture sells fans with the following cost and revenue functions, where x is the number of fans sold, for 0 ≤ x ≤ 6000.
            Cost; C(x) = 0.5x^2 - 0.00003x^3
        Revenue: R(x) = - 1.5x + 0.9x^2 - 0.0001x^3
Given that profit is revenue minus cost, determine the interval on which the profit function is increasing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to study P(x) = R(x) - C(x), where P(x) is the profit function.

The first step is to determine that function:

$$
P(x) = (- 1.5x + 0.9x^{2} - 0.0001x^3) - (0.5x^2 - 0.00003x^3)
$$
$$
P(x) = -1.5 x+0.4 x^2-0.00007 x^3
$$

Now, you need to determine the monotonic intervals of function P. To do this, you need to compute it's derivative:

$$
P'(x) = -1.5+0.8 x-0.00021 x^2
$$

The function P is increasing where the derivative is positive, decreasing where derivative is negative and constant where derivative is 0. So, to determine the interval on which the profit function is increasing, you need to find the interval where P'(x) is positive, for x between 0 and 6000. To do this, you need to rewrite P'(x) as follows:

$$
P'(x) = -0.00021 (-3807.65+x) (-1.87592+x)
$$

and to determine it's sign. It's obvious that equation P'(x) = 0 as 2 solutions, x1 = 3807.65 and x2 = 1.87592, so P'(x) is positive on [1.87592, 3807.65]. This is the interval you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much. You explained everything very well.